# Query to get highest Sum Of Products

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a table that captures sales for different product. What query would i use if i wanted to get the top three products with the highest sales? Am using MS Access as my database.I have used the query below but it doesn't work.

`SELECT TOP(3) productname, SUM(dailysale) As SumOfSales 
FROM tblsales
GROUP BY productname
ORDER BY Sum(dailysale) DESC;`

Comment: Try: `SELECT TOP 3 ...` - no parens around 3.

Comment: Thanks it worked fine

Comment: Then please mark as answered.

Answer (score 0):

```
'SELECT TO(3 productname, SUM(dailysale) As SumOfSales
```

FROM tblsales
GROUP BY productname
ORDER BY Sum(dailysale) DESC;'